# Draw a point at the mean peak of a distplot or kdeplot in Seaborn

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm interested in automatically plotting a point just above the mean peak of a distribution, represented by a kdeplot or distplot with kde.  Plotting points and lines manually is simple, but I'm having difficulty deriving this maximal coordinate point.

For example, the kdeplot generated below should have a point drawn at about (3.5, 1.0):

```
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]
sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width)
```

[image]

This question is serving the ultimate goal to draw a line across to the next peak (two distributions in one graph) with a t-statistic printed above it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The idea here is to first extract the x and y-data of the line object in the plot. Then, get the id of the peak and finally plot the single (x,y) point corresponding to the peak of the distribution.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]
ax = sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width)

x = ax.lines[0].get_xdata() # Get the x data of the distribution
y = ax.lines[0].get_ydata() # Get the y data of the distribution
maxid = np.argmax(y) # The id of the peak (maximum of y data)
plt.plot(x[maxid],y[maxid], 'bo', ms=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this method only shows max of the top most point. What if I have multiple kdemaps plotted and I want max point at each?